# Will rsync "catch-up" a file server that's been down for repair?

Tags: rsync, nas

Let's say I have two NAS boxes (let's call them NAS1 and NAS2) that are rsync'ed. NAS1 is the primary target for all users, but it goes down for an extended period like a couple days or a week in need of repair, such as a power supply failure. We switch to using NAS2 as our target during this period with the intention of switching back to NAS1 when it's operational again.

Once NAS1 is back online, will rsync automatically take care of getting it caught back up to NAS2?

Comment: Nope....you need to update the files on NAS1 first with the new ones that NAS2 has....

Comment: OK, so it's something I would direct manually? Or are you saying I would need to clear NAS1 and rsync everything from NAS2 from scratch?

Comment: This should give the big picture: http://serverfault.com/questions/138287/how-does-rsync-does-incremental-backups